# How to check if file downloaded successfully in Webclient DownloadFileCompleted event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webclient

```
private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I want to check these two cases:

1. If there was an error then do something.
2. If the file was downloaded successfully do something.

Comment: Check if [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917009/web-client-downloadfilecompleted-get-file-name) can help you out for your question

Comment: Is the file coming from a source you control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the [`Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Cancelled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.cancelled(v=vs.110).aspx) properties of the `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` instance:

```
if (e.Error != null)
{
    // there was an error, do something
}
else if (!e.Cancelled)
{
    // file was downloaded fine and completed, do something
}
```